# Prove that $ (v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is a basis for $F^n$ iff the matrix obtained by assembling the coordinate vectors of $v_i$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that a set $S = (v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ of vectors in $F^n$ is a basis $\Longleftrightarrow$ the matrix obtained by assembling the coordinate vectors of $v_i$ is invertible.

$(\Rightarrow):$ Suppose $S$ is basis of $F^n$. We can write every coordinate vector $[v_i]_S$ as $(0,0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)$ where the $1$ is in the $i$th position. The matrix from assembling these vectors is $$M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0  & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$ which is an $n \times n$ identity matrix and so is clearly invertible.

Is this correct so far?

$(\Leftarrow):$ Now assume that the matrix $M$ obtained by assembling the coordinate vectors of $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is invertible. Then there exists an $n \times n$ matrix $N$ such that $MN=NM = I$ where $I$ is an $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Here I get stuck. How do we prove $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ are independent and span $F^n$?

Comment: Everything you've done thus far is fine. I'd personally go about it by assuming that the matrix is invertible yet the vectors don't form a basis for a contradiction. Writing one of the vectors as a linear combination of the others and plugging in, then using multilinearity of the determinant yields that the vectors must be linearly independent. The basis theorem then tells us that they must span the space.

Comment: I don’t think that’s what was meant by “coordinate vectors of $v_i$." I expect that you’re meant to assemble the matrix from the vectors $v_i$ expressed relative to the standard basis so that you must then prove that linear independence of the columns is equivalent to invertibility.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the proof is incorrect. Your $M$ is not the matrix obtained by assembling the vectors $v_i$.

I would say that what an acceptable proof of this fact is depends very much on the order in which theorems have been proved in your book. I would probably say that, letting $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be the standard basis, $M$ represents the linear mapping $\phi$ such that $\phi(e_1)=v_1, \dots, \phi(e_n) = v_n$. You may know that in these circumstances, since $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a basis, $\phi$ is an automorphism of $F^{n}$. Let $N$ be the matrix of $\phi^{-1}$. Then $MN = NM = I$.